# How to port an android studio project from linux to windows

Tags: android, android-studio, import

I have an android project which I am currently working in work PC. It is a Linux machine (Ubuntu 14.04). How can I port this project to my home PC which is Windows 10?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hey Follow this Simple Instruction.

1)   On your Linux Machine After Building and compiling the code
folder will be created

2) Now move the folder to the other machine using Pen drive or other media

now from your Windows machine

3) Open File -> New -> Import project -> Browse directory of folder -> Select folder

Enjoy :D

Answer (score 1):

You can upload your project to [github](https://github.com/) on your linux machine and pull it from there to your Win10 machine.

Git has many advantages,such as multi version,backup and so on.

Answer (score 0):

hey just copy your project from Linux pc and past in windows pc
now simply open project in android studio. it's easy.